# Unable to set the selected value in listbox mold="select" in zk

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, zk

I'm using zk 6.5 and following MVVM pattern , i am facing problem using 
listbox mold="select" i am fetching data from database and want like --select-- as first selected option in my listbox but i can not make it, here is my code

this is my .zul page

```
<listbox style="width:70px" id="lstGrpNames" selectedItem="@bind(vmmodel.selSearchGroup)" mold="select" tabindex="0">

                    </listbox>
```

//this is my controller code

```
@Wire("#lstGrp")
    private Listbox lstGrp;

@AfterCompose(superclass=true)
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);

        if (lstGrp != null) {

            lstGrp.setSelectedItem(lstGrp
                    .appendItem("--Select--", "")); //i want this to be the selected option while page is loaded

            if (this.groups != null && this.groups.size() > 0) {
                for (Group groupObj : this.groups) {
                    lstGrp.appendChild(new Listitem(groupObj.getName(),
                            groupObj));
                }
            }
            lstGrp.setSelectedItem(lstGrp.getItemAtIndex(0));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the MVVM pattern the right way? Normaly the ViewModel should not have any references to the view components. Maybe MVC suits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can do it..

ZUL file of demo code..

```
    <listbox model="@bind(vm.dataList)"  >
        <listhead>
            <listheader value="A"></listheader>
            <listheader value="B"></listheader>
            <listheader value="C"></listheader>

        </listhead>
        <template name="model" var="mymodel">
            <listitem>
                <listcell>

                    <textbox value="@bind(mymodel.a)" />
                </listcell>
                <listcell>
                    <label value="@bind(mymodel.b)" />

                </listcell>
                <listcell>
                    <label value="@bind(mymodel.c)" />

                </listcell>
            </listitem>
        </template>
    </listbox>
</window>
```

Java code of demo code...

```
package com.team;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.AfterCompose;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.NotifyChange;
import org.zkoss.zhtml.Messagebox;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModelList;


public class MyListbox  {

    private ListModelList<Data> dataList;

    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        try {
            dataList = new ListModelList<Data>();
            Data data;
            data = new Data("a1", "b1", "c1");
            dataList.add(data);
            data = new Data("a2", "b2", "c2");
            dataList.add(data);
            data = new Data("a3", "b3", "c3");
            dataList.add(data);
            dataList.addToSelection(dataList.get(0));

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Command
    public void ctrlKeyClick(@org.zkoss.bind.annotation.BindingParam("item") String ctekKeyCode ){
         int keyCode =Integer.parseInt(ctekKeyCode);
         String s = "";
         switch(keyCode){
             case 65: s = "Ctrl+A";break;
             case 119: s = "F8";break;
             case 83:s="Ctrl+S";break;
             case 68:s="Ctrl+D";break;
         }
         Messagebox.show(s+" is pressed", "CtrlKey",
                 Messagebox.OK, Messagebox.EXCLAMATION);
        System.out.println("I am clicked");
    }

    @Command
    @NotifyChange("dataList")
    public void addNewItem(){
        Data data = new Data("", "", "");
        dataList.add(data);
    }


    public ListModelList<Data> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(ListModelList<Data> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }


    public class Data {
        String a;
        String b;
        String c;
        public String getA() {
            return a;
        }
        public String getB() {
            return b;
        }
        public String getC() {
            return c;
        }
        public void setA(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        public void setB(String b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
        public void setC(String c) {
            this.c = c;
        }
        public Data(String a, String b, String c) {
            super();
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

    }
}
```

Here you can check this line of code..

```
dataList.addToSelection(dataList.get(0));
```

this will show you the selected item